# How do I divide my code into two applications?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a few java classes, holding my application's logic. Now I want to create two applications, one will be a SpringBoot web application and another one will be a desktop application. Both of them will use logic, that I already wrote.
I see only one way to do it: compiling logic classes into a `.jar` file and then putting it as a library into two Idea projects. But if I update any of this code, I will have to recompile it into jar and then replace an old jar with a new one in both projects.

1. Is there another, more simple way two divide my code into two projects?
2. What should I do with Git/GitHub?

P.S.
My project is in java, I use Intellij IDEA, GitHub.

Comment: You can simply use one project and three modules: 1 library with the common code and 2 applications using the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Multi-module project

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70609782/how-do-i-divide-my-code-into-two-applications/70610663#comment124820451_70609782), you need a multi-module project. The content for each module is compiled separately, producing separate JAR files.

[IntelliJ supports multi-module](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html) projects.

I recommend using a Java build management tool to assist.

- [*Apache Maven*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) is one such tool that [supports multiple modules](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html).
- [*Apache Gradle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle) may be even better for multi-module projects.

---

The word “module” used here in this context should not be confused for the [*Java Platform Module System*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System). You may or may not choose to use Java modules in your project modules’ code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest rest web service interface to export the logic data..

SpringBoot web application can consume the rest services
and the other a desktop application can consume the rest services

```
ONE REST SERVICE LAYER
--------------------------------------
 |                 |
Desktop app,     SpringBoot web application
```

this way to don't duplicate your code and bugs twice.